# Array of different types in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, types

Is it possible to make array of different variable types?
For example,

```
int p1[]={1, 2, 3};
float p2[]={1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
double p3[]={...};
...
...

arr[0].ptr = p1;
arr[1].ptr = p2;
...
```

At first, I tried to solve this with enum, void* ptr and std::same with templates. I did it, but it looks really dirty. Like this.

```
enum dataType{...}
struct arr{
    void *p
    dataType datatype
}
template<typename T>
void insert(T x){
    if(std::is_same<T, int*>) /* ... */
    else if(std::is_same<T, float*>) /* ... */
    ...
}
void foo(int a, int b){
    std::cout<<(TYPE_CHANGE_SOMEHOW)arr[a].ptr[b]<<std::endl;
}
// and much more
```

So I'm looking for other way.

- std::tuple needs to be declared with specific types, so I can't use them.
- only using void* cannot work with index access

Comment: If you can use `c++17` std::any or std::variant could be a good option.

Comment: @super If you ever find yourself using `std::any`, you’ve got a design flaw. OTOH, `std::variant` or a polymorphic class is not nearly as bad.

Comment: @Kerndog73 Almost everything has it's use cases. I think a better phrasing would be that `std::any` should never be the first choice, especially if the motivation is convenience.

Comment: What are you declaring in the first few lines? You’re initialising an array of pointers to integers with an initialiser list of integers. I can’t figure out what you’re trying to do. Also, why aren’t you using `std::vector` or `std::array`?

Comment: I think what you want is a template class derived from a polymorphic base but I don’t know enough of the specifics to write a proper example. What design decisions lead you to this problem anyway?

Comment: @Kerndog73 first few lines are miswritten. I've corrected them.

Comment: @Kerndog73 std::vector's element must be a single type, so I can't use them.

Comment: @Kerndog73 I'm rewriting my old codes for drawing a plot. If I put multiple arrays such as y=sinx float and y=x double, the plot class stores input pointer inside. So I want to make plotData struct array for storing different pointer types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider a `std::array` or `std::vector` of [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
std::vector<std::variant<int, float>> vvec;
vvec.push_back(42);
vvec.push_back(3.1415);

try
{
   std::get<float>(vvec[0]); // vvec[0] contains int, not float: will throw
}
catch (const std::bad_variant_access&)
{
    // Handle exception
}
```

Comment: I think this suits, I'll give it a try

Comment: Yeah, this is what I want.
Unfortunately, my version is lower than c++17

Comment: @김선달 Then use what std::variant is based on: [boost::variant](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html)